# How to fetch Records from Sqlite based on From date and to date

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to fetch the records from SQLite database based on from date and to date. 
For example: Fetch the Records who has birthDay between 2 Feb to 5 March. 
The problem is that the DOB column also store birthday year of person and I don't want to consider the year to fetch records. 
The Format to store DOB in the database is DD-mm-YYYY (02-02-1990).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create other 2 columns, which store only Day and Month. then the Query example is

```
select * from table1 where day between  1 and 5 and month between 2 and 5
```

Comment: This Query will not work when the day is same for example from 10 Feb to 10 June.I have resolved this bug with bellow Query in New Answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Concatenate MonthDayFields and use between statement to fetch records

// This Query will Fetch Records From 5 Oct to 5 Apr 

SELECT *,substr('00'||DOB_Month,-2,2) || substr('00'||DOB_Day, -2, 2)
as 'myField' FROM Table1
WHERE (myField BETWEEN "1005" AND "1231") OR (myField  BETWEEN "0101" AND "0405")


// This Query will Fetch Records From 5 Apr to 18 Oct

SELECT *,substr('00'||DOB_Month,-2,2) || substr('00'||DOB_Day, -2, 2)
as 'myField' FROM Table1
WHERE myField between "0405" and "1018"
```